# Web API | How to authenticate a side service that does not have the normal login functionality

Tags: c#, security, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on a project that uses a C# Web API. We are using JWT tokens.

We have the authentication setup for the main application that is hitting our web API.

We also have a side service that needs to authenticate to use the web API, but they do not have the necessary items to authenticate because they do not have an account.

Is there a "secure" way to authenticate a side service that does not have the normal login functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want an app that is not authenticated by login but still protected?. This is really not a very good implementation. In case you want to do this. You can try the solution using rsa body request encryption algorithms with signature includes in header and check. If it matches then you can implement your logics. Hope to be useful.

Comment: Thanks for this information. So I could pass Guid (Signature) in the header to our web api with RSA algorithm and then validate it on our web API to make sure they match? Something like this ? https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/75a48f/rsa-algorithm-with-C-Sharp2/

Comment: Yes. Let do this. You can make both app using only one rsa algorithm.